# Is it possible to export loadrunner analysis data into excel automatically?If yes how can I achieve this?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Every time I execute performance test on loadrunner, it will automatically export the results into excel. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Yes, look at the templates available inside of the Analysis.   You can exit a test, automatically start analysis with a  default template that does all sorts of stuff, including exports.  You could also complement this with workflow which automatically issued queries to the results database for custom queries and output.

Covered in documentation for analysis

Answer (score 0):

You can build macro for importing [session_name].mdb file of analysis session to get required data in excel , you can add queries for required recordset